# InputField - use later as a function

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

This is my attempt at trying to write code to do the following. 
I want the user to Input the function - I then want to create a new function called g[x_] that I can use later to do things like evaluate g[6] or Solve equations etc...

```
ClearAll[f, g]
LocalizeVariables -> False;
Interpretation[
 Panel[
  Grid[
   {
    {"Function f(x):", InputField[Dynamic[f]], g[x_] := Function[f][x]}
    }
   ]
  ],
 ]
Dynamic[g[x]]
```

But nothing happens - it seems g[x] does not contain the input function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess this is what you want:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
Panel[Grid[{{"Function f(x):", InputField[Dynamic[f, (g[x_] = f = #) &]]}}]]
Dynamic[g[x]]
```

Or maybe this, but it requires entering your function in terms of [`Slot[1]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and not `x`:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
Panel[Grid[{{"Function f(x):", InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
    g[x_] := Function[Evaluate@f][x]}}]]
Dynamic[g[x]]
```

So probably the first one is closer to what you want.  But be careful to never assign `x` a numeric value.  If you do, `x` will not work as a variable.

If you want a more bullet-proof version, here's a modification:

```
Panel[Grid[{{"Function f(x):", 
    InputField[Dynamic[f, Block[{x}, g[x_] = ReleaseHold[f = #]] &],
      Hold[Expression]]}}]]
```

`Block[{x},...]` temporarily clears an values `x` has while the definition of `g` is created.  The type argument `Hold[Expression]` keeps `x` from being evaluated inside the input field, so that it will behave as a variable.

Comment: The third code Panel[Grid[{{"Funct.......  did exactly what I want, I can now get on with the rest of my code. Thank you Michael E2 for taking the time to do this , I literally spent hours trying to figure out what was needed and now I am happy :-)